# Sapper: setClient() is throwing "Function called outside component initialization"

Tags: graphql, svelte, sapper

I am trying to implement graphql in sapper with apollo-boost and svelte-apollo by declaring a new ApolloClient in the _layout.svelte and setClient. Declaring the ApolloClient works just fine but when it comes to setClient it thows an:

> Error: Function called outside component initialization

Here the script tag in my _layout.svelte

```
<script>
    import Nav from '../components/Nav.svelte';
    export let segment;

    import fetch from 'node-fetch'
    import ApolloClient from "apollo-boost";
    import { setClient } from "svelte-apollo";

    const client = new ApolloClient({
        uri: "http://localhost:1337/graphql",
        fetch: fetch,

        onError: ({ networkError, graphQLErrors }) => {
            console.log("graphQLErrors", graphQLErrors);
            console.log("networkError", networkError);
        },
    })

    setClient(client)

</script>
```

Comment: You need to load it in a preload functino - https://github.com/jdgamble555/sapper-urql-ssr

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer myself, at least svelte-apollo needs to be an devDependencie. I made apollo-boost and graphql devDependencies, too, but I dont know if its necessary

Comment: How will it run in production then?!